# Simplify solution of trigonometric equation

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I use this code to solve equation `Sin[2x]==0]`

```
Reduce[Sin[2 x] == 0, x]
```

> C[1] ∈
> Integers && (x == π C[1] || x == 1/2 (π + 2 π C[1]))

How can I get the roots of this equation in the form `x == π C[1]/2`?

PS. When I solve by hand, I tried
`Reduce[2 x == k Pi, x]`

Comment: Even the simpler case `Reduce[Sin[t] == 0, t]` returns the convoluted `Element[C[1], Integers] && (t == 2*Pi*C[1] || t == Pi + 2*Pi*C[1])` in MMA 13.3.0 on the cloud.

Comment: `FindSequenceFunction[x/.Solve[Sin[2 x]==0&&0<=x<20Pi,x],k+1]`