# Simplify solutions of trigonometric equation has the form Sin[a]==Sin[b]

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I am trying to solve the equation
$$ \sin\left(2 x + \dfrac{\pi}{5} \right) = \sin \left(3 x-\dfrac{2 \pi }{7} \right).  $$
My code

```
Clear[a, b];
a = 2 x + Pi/5;
b = 3 x - 2*Pi/7;
TrigExpand@Reduce[Sin[a] == Sin[b], x, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

I get

[image]

I solve by my hand.

```
Clear[a, b];
a = 2 x + Pi/5;
b = 3 x - 2*Pi/7;
Reduce[{a == Pi - b + 2 * k * Pi || a == b +  2 * k * Pi}, x]
```

I get

> x == (17 [Pi])/35 - 2 k [Pi] || x == (38 [Pi])/175 + (2 k [Pi])/5

How I tell Mathematica to get the solutions like that?

I also post at [here](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/236707-How-Do-I-Solve-This-Trigonometric-Equation-Has-The-Form-Cosa#answer295893)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to adapt your code is to apply `TrigFactor` to your equation before feeding it into `Reduce`:

```
Reduce[TrigFactor[Sin[a] - Sin[b]] == 0, x, Reals] // FullSimplify

(* C[1] \[Element] Integers && 
  (x == 2/175 π (19 - 70 C[1]) || 
   x == -(4/175) π (8 + 35 C[1]) || 
   x == π (17/35 - 4 C[1]) ||
   x == π (-(53/35) - 4 C[1])) *)
```

This is not the most parsimonious way of writing out the solution set — the method you find by hand is definitely more elegant.  (Effectively, the last two options in this output correspond to the first option in your solution, while the first two options in this output correspond to the second option in your solution.)  Still, this is a more elegant solution the default output.

Comment: of course+1. This is the same method I used with FullSimplify just reconfiguring the same 4 general solutions.  The general solution in update1 and another way of presenting it update 2. I am still somewhat confused by what “simple solution”means.

Comment: Please see another question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287280/simplify-solution-of-trigonometric-equation

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2**

Perhaps, this is a simplifcation:

The "base" solution:

```
base = x /. {ToRules[
    Reduce[{TrigFactor[u - v] == 0, 0 < x < 2 Pi}, x]]}
```

yields:

```
{(38 π)/175, (17 π)/35, (108 π)/175, (178 π)/175, (
 248 π)/175, (318 π)/175}
```

The general solution is $2 \pi$ + the "base solution"

For example:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Highlighted[TrigFactor[u - v], 
   Placed["Ball", List /@ (base + 2 Pi k)]], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}], {k, 
  Range[-2, 2]}]
```

[image]

**Update**

In relation to comment:

```
sol = Reduce[TrigFactor[u - v] == 0, x];
Expand /@ (x /. {ToRules[sol[[2]]]})
```

yields:

```
{(38 π)/175 - (4 π C[1])/5, -((32 π)/175) - (
  4 π C[1])/5, (17 π)/35 - 4 π C[1], -((53 π)/35) - 
  4 π C[1]}
```

where the $c_1$ are integers. See original answer below `u`, `v`.

**Original Answer**

Restricting problem:

```
u = Sin[2 x + Pi/5];
v = Sin[3 x - 2 Pi/7];
pts = {x, 
   u} /. {ToRules[
    Reduce[{TrigFactor[u - v] == 0, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x]]}
```

yields:

```
{{(38 π)/175, Cos[(47 π)/350]}, {(17 π)/
  35, -Sin[(6 π)/35]}, {(108 π)/175, -Cos[(23 π)/350]}, {(
  178 π)/175, Sin[(41 π)/175]}, {(248 π)/
  175, -Sin[(6 π)/175]}, {(318 π)/175, -Sin[(29 π)/175]}}
```

As can be seen:

```
  Plot[{u, Highlighted[v, Placed["Ball", List /@ pts[[All, 1]]]]}, {x, 
  0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want Restrict my problem.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 I have updated my answer.

Comment: Can you simplify all solutions?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 the solutions are simple and much simpler than questions. I may leave you to further simplify.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287280/simplify-solution-of-trigonometric-equation

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we can easily find the general solution of $\cos(x)=0$ and $\sin(x)=0$ (alternative form), where $k$ is an integer

```
FindSequenceFunction[x /. Solve[#[x] == 0 && 0 <= x < 10 Pi, x], k + 1] & /@ 
  {Cos, Sin} // Simplify
```

> $\left\{\left(\frac{1}{2}+k\right) \pi ,k \pi \right\}$

Then perform rules replacement

```
eqn = TrigFactor[Sin[a] - Sin[b]] == 0 /. 
  {a -> 2 x + Pi/5, b -> 3 x - 2 Pi/7} /. 
  {Cos[x_] :> (x - (k + 1/2) Pi), Sin[x_] :> x - k Pi};
Solve[eqn, x] // Expand
```

> $\left\{\left\{x\to \frac{38 \pi }{175}+\frac{2 k \pi }{5}\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{17 \pi }{35}-2 k \pi \right\}\right\}$